# Add key and value to an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two objects and I need to create one new  array with a new structure for example:
These are my objects:

Object 1:
[{
"Question":"Climate change",
"Total":"3.456"
}]

Object 2:
[{
"Question":"Climate change",
"Total":"3.567"
}]

I need this Output

[{
"x":3.456,
"y":3.567
}]

I tried creating the array I need with one of the arrays... So I used the first array to have: [{y:3.456}] and it works, now I need to add the x key and the value from the second array so I tried this:

Where chardatavalue is one of the arrays(which contains the "y" key and the value) and arrayforxls2 is the other one, but the code I have only assign the last value of the seconf array to all of the "x" keys.

```
var resultnew = chartdatavalue.map(function (el) {
 var o = Object.assign({}, el);

     for (let i of arrayforxls2) {
         
         o.x = i.Total;
                
      }
      return o;
    });
```

chartdatavalue has this structure:

```
[{
y: '3.893'
}]
```

arrayxls2 has this structure:

```
[{
"Question":"Climate change",
"Total":"3.567"
}]
```

I need this output:

[{
"x":3.567,
"y":3.893
}]
Can you please help me.

Comment: Show your efforts.

Comment: I edited my question trincot, Thanks.

Comment: What is `arrayforxls2`? It is nowhere defined. And what is the value of `chartdatavalue`. Please provide the code that is needed for *us* to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ok, I added what contains chartdatavalue and arrayforxls2

Comment: I don't understand which logic you want to apply to those two objects to produce a merged object. `arrayforxls2` has one number, and `arrayforxls2` three. How does that map?

Comment: They have the same number of objects, I just put those as an example, cause they have two many, and I can't put them here because it's too much.. I just need to have an output like this: [{ "x":3.456, "y":3.567 }] the "y" key from the chartdatavalue and add the "x key from the arrayforxls value "Total" that's what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you are looking for this:

```
var resultnew = chartdatavalue.map(function (el, i) {
    return Object.assign({ x: arrayforxls2[i].Total }, el);
});
```

The change here is that `i` is captured and used, so that the i<sup>th</sup> object from the one array is merged with the i<sup>th</sup> of the other.

You can also use object spread syntax instead of `Object.assign` for this:

```
var resultnew = chartdatavalue.map((el, i) =>
    ({ x: arrayforxls2[i].Total, ...el})
);
```

Or, when there are other properties in `el` that you need to ignore, then with object destructuring:

```
var resultnew = chartdatavalue.map(({y}, i) =>
    ({ x: arrayforxls2[i].Total, y})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var resultnew = chartdatavalue.map((el, i) => ({x: el.Total, y: arrayforxls2[i].Total}));
```

This iterates over one of the arrays, and uses the index `i` to get the value from the corresponding object in the other array.

There's no point in using `Object.assign()` since the result objects don't include any of the property names of the input objects.